# How to start in the middle of a database table and loop through?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database table that contains 4 columns (id, title, image, text). There are 120 rows altogether, and I want to loop through all the rows. I know I could just do this (using MySQLi):

```
$resultSet = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Table");

        if ($resultSet->num_rows != 0)
        {
             while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
             {
                   //Do something
             }
        }
```

But what I am trying to do is this: Display the information in three columns, like this for example:

```
1            3         5 
[Title]   [title]   [title] 
[image]   [image]   [image] 
[text]    [text]    [text]

2            4         6 
[Title]   [title]   [title] 
[image]   [image]   [image] 
[text]    [text]    [text]
```

The id's are there just for reference, and won't be displayed. I want to have 3 columns, each containing 40 rows. My problem that I am trying to solve is that, when the first column gets done displaying the first 40 rows in the database table, how can I go back to the top so the second and third column get created next to each other? Would I need 3 loops altogether, each loop with its own div? If so, how would I accomplish making 3 loops, each loop looping through 40 rows each?

Comment: You can put the condition in your loop when rows are > 40 you need to move to next column!

Comment: If you're using php >= 5.4.0 you can use `mysqli::data_seek()` to move backwards and forwards through the result set. You'd read a row, jump +40, read the next row, jump +40 and read the third row, output the three columns of data, then jump -79 and do it again. You might also be able to wrap the table using CSS, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

no need to loop back.  save every 40 rows inside a variable like this

```
if ($resultSet->num_rows != 0)
{
    $count = 40;
    $ctr = 1;
    $index = 0;
    $cols = array();
    while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
    {        
        if($ctr <= $count){
            $cols[$index] = $rows;
        }
        if($ctr >= $count){
            $count += 40; 
            $index++;
        }        
        $ctr++;
    }
    print_r($cols);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($resultSet->num_rows != 0)
{
   ?>
   <table>
      <tr>
      <?php
      $i = 0;

      while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
      {
        $i++;
        ?>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>image</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>title</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>price</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <?php 
        if($i == 3)
        {
          $i = 0;
          echo "</tr>";
          echo "<tr>";
        }
      }
      ?>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <?php
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have too many (thousands) of rows to display, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ORDER BY IF(id % 2, id - 100000, id);
```

This assumes that your id does not exceed 100000, if it does, make that constant bigger.

The idea is that we come up with a function that preserves the order of odd numbers when compared against each other, same for even number, but always makes the even win (be bigger than) against the odd thus putting it later in the order. If you need a different order, you can play with the `IF()` to make it just right.